# Added reactivity to Alpine.data component, but it's not working

Tags: alpine.js

I've a simple Alpinejs component named "glide". I'm passing a configuration object, making it reactive with `Alpine.reactive`:

```js
  Alpine.data('glide', (config = {}) => ({
    glide: null,
    init() {
      this.config = Alpine.reactive(config);
      Alpine.effect(() => {
        console.log('effect', this.config);
      });

      this.glide = new Glide(this.$el, this.config);
      this.glide.mount();
    },
  }));
```

For some reason the `Alpine.effect` isn't invoked, but the view reflect the updated `config.perView` value:

```html
<div x-data="glide({ perView: 1 })">
  <button @click="config.perView++">
    Increase perView (current: <span x-text="config.perView"></span>)
  </button>
</div>
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: I just tried this in a fiddle and it seems to be working. https://jsfiddle.net/3pc1bwkx/

Maybe there's an issue with the `Glide` class?

Comment: @CalvinFurano thanks, it seems it work fine in your fiddle. let me check in my code.

Comment: you don't need Alpine.reactive(), just do `this.config = config;`. all properties of alpine component is proxied.